# how do I set a field with a duplicate name of another field in mechanize?

Tags: python, forms, duplicates, mechanize

I am trying to submit a form with 2 fields with the same name but different type. I can identify the correct field I want by the field type or the number. Whats the best way of setting the correct field without iterating through all the fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the signature of set_value() method of HTMLForm class.

```
set_value(value, name=None, type=None, kind=None,
          id=None, nr=None,by_label=False,
          # by_label is deprecated 
          label=None)
```

As you can see, you could specify `type` parameter, useful in this case to select the proper field.